# How do I make the image show on the DOM via this API call using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, dom-manipulation

I hate asking a question that I believe has been covered in some way on Stack Overflow but I haven't been able to find enough instruction on how to do this.

I would like to render the image which has an id of 'gulp'.
I am not sure of how to go about doing this.

I am just learning how to do API calls using fetch (I have been working through a few different tasks).

codepen:
https://codepen.io/matthew-palmer/pen/ZEzXaOd

I am not sure what to do but have tried using `innerHTML` and `textContent`. I have seen some examples citing `setAttribute` as well.

```html
<body> 
  <div>
    <img src='' 
         id='gulp' 
         alt='randomdrink'>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
const drink = document.querySelector('#gulp').src

fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
    .then(response => {return response.json()
    }).then(response => 
          drink.textContent = response.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb)
```

```css
#gulp {
  text-align:center;
  outline: deeppink solid 2px;
  margin-left: 48%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

I am expecting an image to show on the page. I have gotten the URL to show in the past but not the image.

Comment: document.querySelector("#gulp").src = response.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `src` of an image that way, cause `src` is an attribute.

Try this:

```
const gulp = document.querySelector('#gulp')

fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php')
    .then(response => {return response.json()
    }).then(response => 
          gulp.src = response.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you!